# Iterate over third-level JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, facebook-graph-api

Help! This has been bugging the crap out of me.

I'm accessing data through Facebook's Graph API. How do I get the application name?

```
{
     "data": [
          {
             "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.",
             "application": {
                "name": "Instagram",
                "namespace": "instapp",
                "id": "000000"
             }
          },
          {
             "message": "2 Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.",
             "application": {
                "name": "Instagram",
                "namespace": "instapp",
                "id": "000000"
             }
          }
       ]
}
```

My code so far:

```
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){                       
    for( i=0; i < data.data.length; i++){
        var fbApp = data.data[i].application
        var fbMessage =  data.data[i].message;
        $(".facebook").append('<p>'+ fbMessage +'</p>');   
    }               
});
```

Output for variable `fbApp` would be `[object Object]` or `undefined`.

Amending `data.data[i].application` to `data.data[i].application['name']` gives me the name but of only 1 object, so the loop stops.

It seems I would need to reloop over object[key] (e.g. data[message]) to get to application[name]. How do I do this?

Comment: That JSON code seems to be missing a couple `}`

Comment: It was a partial copy and paste from the FB open graph... I didn't take time to validate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is not valid. Should be:

```
 "data": [
      {
         "message": "Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.",
         "application": {
            "name": "Instagram",
            "namespace": "instapp",
            "id": "000000"
         }
      },
      {
         "message": "2 Lorem ipsum dolor site amet.",
         "application": {
            "name": "Instagram",
            "namespace": "instapp",
            "id": "000000"
         }
      }
   ]
```

Also fbApp (based on var fbApp = data.data[i].application) IS an object (application), so if you want to access the application.name then you do fbApp.name

Comment: OK, well, it was a copy and paste from the FB open graph... I didn't take time to validate it.

Comment: I have done `data.data[i].application.name` but it stops at the first loop.

Comment: Should work. Created example here: http://jsfiddle.net/martemas/zSHDh/ I've striped the getJSON bit and assuming data is in the format above.

Comment: I have added extra curly brackets at the beginning and end of the JSON data sample. I would JSfiddle it but I'm using a private access token.

Comment: Updated my jsfiddle. Play with it and probably cut/paste your actual data and run it.

Comment: I can't get the data using your access token as it has expired. However try log the content of effFB. Possible issue is in the first scenario the data.application is undefined due to some issues - therefore caused it to crash as you try to access the name attribute. The second scenario  - since you dont access its name attribute - was successful even though application may be undefined. Also try log the data.application value and see if it is undefined (I suspect it is in the subsequent loop). Need the content of effFB to help further. Also try this: http://jsfiddle.net/martemas/HVzsL/2/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31234/discussion-between-aaa-and-maethorr)